# Can I get a Supervised Instruction Permit at 17 in Idaho?

Tags: driving

I'm almost 17 in Idaho. I don't have a burning desire to drive, but it would be nice for a few reasons. Driving with my parents is fine.

Given this, I'd like to stay under a 'supervised instruction permit' (SIP), the "you can drive, but only with a licensed adult" version of a license. I also don't really want to go through driver's training and all that red tape.

It seems I could walk into the DMV, take the test, and get my 'real' license when I turn 17 (or that's how I read the first bullet list on http://itd.idaho.gov/dmv/driverservices/driver_license_facts.html).

For insurance purposes, it would be better for me to have an SIP.

**Can I get an SIP when I turn 17 without going through driver's training?** For how long would it be valid? The DMV website seems fuzzy on this; I would imagine it's a rare case for someone to not want a full license.

Comment: It looks like it. Here's [the page](http://itd.idaho.gov/dmv/DriverServices/young_drivers.html) for "young driver's."

Comment: @mkennedy I've looked at that page before, but I didn't think I found what I was looking for - could you point me to the section you're looking at there?

Comment: Yeah, it's unclear because there's not positive statements, they're all negative ones. Let's see what the driver's instruction manual says...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The online [Young Drivers](http://itd.idaho.gov/dmv/DriverServices/young_drivers.html) webpage is unclear because there's nothing really stating what is required for people who are 17. If you're under 17, you have to take a driver training program.

In the [Idaho Driver's Manual](http://itd.idaho.gov/dmv/DriverServices/documents/driver_manual.pdf), there is an explicit statement on page 1-3:

> If you have not successfully completed driver training and the GDL
>   Program, you must pass a written knowledge test and be at least 17
>   years old to be issued an instruction permit. The permit may be renewed
>   one (1) time without requiring the permit holder to retake and pass
>   the Class D knowledge test, provided the previous knowledge test was
>   taken within the past 12 months.

Here is a list of documentation (or people) that you may need to have with you:

```
1. Proof of Age and Identity
2. Social Security Card or Number for Verification
3. Proof of Idaho Residency
4. Acceptable Lawful Presence Documents (if applicable)
5. Foreign Driver’s License (if applicable)
6. Visual/Medical Certification (if applicable)
7. Driver Training Completion (if under 17)
8. Liability Signer (if under 18)
9. Verification of School Compliance – VOC (if under 18)
```

There's what I would call another unclear section on page 1-5 in the Driver Training/Supervised Instruction Section:

> Anyone 17 years of age or older may take driver training with either
>   the Driver Training/Supervised Instruction Permit or with the Class D
>   Instruction Permit. The knowledge test must be passed before a Class D
>   Instruction Permit can be issued. While you are enrolled in a driver’s
>   training program, the Driver Training/Supervised Instruction Permit is
>   valid only to operate a vehicle with a driver training instructor.

Okay, so you definitely have to pass the knowledge test before getting a Class D Instruction Permit. I think the last sentence means that if you have the Driver Training/Supervised instruction Permit you can only drive with a licensed instructor. That limitation does not apply to a Class D Instruction Permit.

Answer (score 1):

I finally just called the DMV. I don't have a citation for it, but I was told that I could get a 'learner's permit' after taking a written test when I turn 17, which would be valid for me to drive with adults.

It should still count as a permit for insurance purposes, and I wouldn't have to do driver's training.